# Construct function from string

Tags: function-construction

I'm looking for a way to build a function from an input string in a text box for use in graphics. This is the indended functionality:

```
DynamicModule[
 {f = "x^2 + Sin[y]", x, y},
 Column[{
   Row[{"f(x,y)=", InputField[Dynamic[f]]}],
   Row[{"f= ", Dynamic[f]}],
   Plot3D[ToExpression[f][x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
   }]
 ]
```

Notably, I'd like to support any form (not strictly c₁·x² + c₂·Sin[y]) and a variable number of arguments (though I'll need to know how many arguments when I try to plot it).

I've tried some approaches using [ToExpression](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html) and [Symbol](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Symbol.html) with no luck. I did manage to define a function inside the inputbox, ie:

```
f[x_]:=x^2;     {ENTER}
f[3]            {ENTER}
```

↳ Modifies the inputbox to display 9, but I can't seem to extract that f[] that I defined.

I also tried to modify the code in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/108155/convert-string-to-function-with-an-argument), but I still couldn't get the expression to be stored as a function like the asker requested there.

Am I missing something, or is this behavior not really possible in Mathematica?

Comment: Quite old but seems to be about that: [26985](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26985/5478), also related: [783](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/783/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you need to use strings? What's wrong with:

```
DynamicModule[{f=x^2 + Sin[y]},
    Column[{
        Row[{"f(x,y)=", InputField[Dynamic[f]]}],
        Dynamic @ Plot3D[f,{x,0,1},{y,0,1}]
    }]
]
```

Comment: Silly me, thinking that inputboxes had to return strings. Mathematica is magic.

Comment: There are edge cases, normally `f[x_] := x/x` for `x = 0`will give `Indeterminate` but here `x/x` will give `1` for `x = 0`

Comment: @Kuba There is always `InputField[Dynamic[f], Hold[Expression]]`, although then the Plot3D evaluation is trickier.

Comment: @CarlWoll yep, I know, your solution is probably all that is needed here yet it is good to keep those issues in mind.